# (Prolog) Get sum of variables without list

Tags: math, prolog, sum

very new to Prolog and I'm absolutely awful at it.

I am trying to get a sum for all the marks received on assignments, and return it. The sum predicate must be of the form `sumAssignments(S)`.

Here's the knowledge base I've made:

```
assignment(1, A).
assignment(2, B).
assignment(3, C).
assignment(4, D).
assignment(5, E).
```

...Where `assignment(1, A)` means that assignment 1 has a variable grade A (could be 70, could be 50, etc.).

Here is my attempt at getting the sum, just for the first two assignments for testing purposes:

```
sumAssignments(S) :- assignment(1, A), assignment(2, B), S=A+B.
```

That always returns yes. The key here is I can't use lists.

Comment: Does "assignment(1, A)" mean that assignment 1 had a grade of A, or that assignment A has a grade of 1?  Is is the numbers 1 through 5 that you are trying to sum?

Comment: assignment(1, A) means that assignment 1 has a variable grade of A (this is entered in as a query), I've clarified in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that only constants belong in predicates, so instead of `assignment(1, A).` we would find an arbitrary number to represent 'A', in this case maybe 67 or 100: `assignment(1, 67).` The summation works fine after doing that.

Comment: Why not use the atoms  `a` to `f`?